# Dependent Assembly does not Appear in Application Files list in Publish Settings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, nuget, clickonce

I have an application that is written in .NET 4.0 but uses C# 5.0's async/await semantics. To make this work, I included the [Microsoft Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) NuGet package in the project (which depends on the [Microsoft BCL Portability Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/)). This added the following references to the project:

- Microsoft.Threading.Tasks (1.0.12.0)
- Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions (1.0.12.0)
- Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop (1.0.168.0)
- System.IO (2.6.10.0)
- System.Runtime (2.6.10.0)
- System.Threading.Tasks (2.6.10.0)

And it added the following binding redirection in the app.config:

```
<runtime>
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.10.0" newVersion="2.6.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.10.0" newVersion="2.6.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
 </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

So far so good; everything works fine inside Visual Studio. All six assemblies appear in the output folder. However, when I deployed this via ClickOnce, the application crashes almost immediately. The root cause appears to be this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=2.6.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Sure enough, this file wasn't part of the manifest. When I look in the 'Application Files' list under the 'Publish' tab of the project properties, the first three assemblies (Microsoft.*) are included, but the last three assemblies (System.*) do not appear at all. Selecting 'Show all files' does not help. I can only guess that it's ignoring these because they are System.* assemblies for which there already exists an entry in the GAC.

How can I make Visual Studio recognize these System.* assemblies as dependencies that need to be deployed via ClickOnce?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?